# How to target isotope data-filter with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-isotope, attr

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html

I am using isotope to filter some elements. I want to show/hide a button if that filter(from the navigation menu) is currently active:

jquery:

```
if($('nav.primary ul a').attr('.designs') == true){
        $(".loadMore").show();  
    }
else{$(".loadMore").hide();}
```

html:

```
<nav class="primary clearfix">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="selected" data-filter=".designs">Designs<span class="count">27</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".flash">Flash<span class="count">11</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it by doing:

```
$('nav.primary ul a').click(function(){
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        if (selector !== ".designs"){
            $(".loadMore").hide();
        }
        else {
            $(".loadMore").show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute name is data-filter, so i think your condition should be

```
if($('nav.primary ul a').attr('data-filter') == ".designs"){
    $(".loadMore").show();  
}
else{
    $(".loadMore").hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Still not working though, the button doesn't hide when I click the next link(Flash) which has a different data-filter.

Comment: can you write a jsFiddle, so that i can check and correct it?

Comment: I think the .attr is wrong so I used `if($('nav.primary ul a[data-filter=designs]') == true){$(".loadMore").show();}` but still not working